# HTML, CSS Text floating inside DIV

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="right-details">
    <div class="right-details-row">
        <b>Left title</b>
    </div>            
    <div class="right-details-row">
        <div class="right-details-row-l">K</div>
        <div class="right-details-row-r">Laass</div>                  
    </div>                                                            
</div>  
<div class="details-divider"></div>
<div class="left-details">
    <div class="left-details-row">
        <b>Right Title</b>
    </div>               
    <div class="left-details-row">
        <div class="left-details-row-l">Option 1</div>
        <div class="left-details-row-r">Chosen 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-details-row">
        <div class="left-details-row-l">Option 2</div>
        <div class="left-details-row-r">Chosen 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-details-row">
        <div class="left-details-row-l">Option 2</div>
        <div class="left-details-row-r">Chosen 2</div>
    </div>             
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left-details{
   display:table-cell;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   border-radius: 4px;
   width:237px;
}
.details-divider{
    width:20px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.right-details{
   margin-left: 20px;
   display:table-cell;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   border-radius: 4px;  
   width:350px;
}
.left-details-row{
   width: 232px;
   float:left;
   margin: 0 0 5px 4px;
}
.left-details-row-l{
   width:110px;
   float:left;
   overflow:hidden;   
}
.left-details-row-r{
   width:122px;
   float:left;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.right-details-row{
   width: 345px;
   float:left;
   margin: 0 0 5px 4px;
}
.right-details-row-l{
   width: 35px;
   float:left;
   margin: 0 0 2px 4px;
}
.right-details-row-r{
   width: 296px;
   float:left;
   overflow:hidden;   
}
```

As you see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f26dr/1/) , in the left `Div` text is in the bottom, How to shift it to the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to your `.right-details` rule:

```
.right-details {
    margin-left: 20px;
    display:table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width:350px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f26dr/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

add

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to .right-details

Answer (score 0):

```
.left-details{
   display:table-cell;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   border-radius: 4px;
   width:237px;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

note the last property

http://jsfiddle.net/V5JtR/1/